# What is best practice when NOT using storyboards or nibs?

Tags: ios, uiview, uistoryboard

I've heard Facebook and Google do not use UIStoryboards or nibs because they are difficult to merge – they format all their views programmatically. Are there any resources out there that can provide some guidance as to how best to position assets, handle localization, organize files, etc., when creating all your views without nibs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to create an UINavigationController or a UITabBarController within the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching method, where you should set the rootViewController for the current UIWindow (`[window setRootViewController:]`).

Then you just have to create your content viewcontrollers and views. Let's say you want to create a menu, then you should create a MneuViewController which inherits from UIViewController and a MenuView which inherits from UIView. Within the MenuView code you create your view components like labels, textfields or whatever you need. In the MenuViewController you create an instance of the MenuView class and call `[self setView:]` with that object. Finally you have to add the ViewControllers to your rootViewController.
The AppDelegate should look similar to something like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
        MenuViewController *mvc = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: mvc];
        [self.window setRootViewController: rootViewController];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Localization has to be done using the macro `NSLocalizedString()` for which you should find a lot of samples.

Files should be handled using NSFileManager.

For eveything else you should ask more specific questions.